# How to get the declared variables ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr

I have the following parser rule

```
study: 'study' '(' ( assign* | ( assign (',' assign)*) ) ')' NEWLINE;
assign: ID '=' (INT  | DATA );
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
DATA    : '"' ID '"' | '"' INT '"';
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
```

my problem now how I can retrieve the variables defined in the study in the entryStudy method

```
@Override
    public void enterStudy(StudyParser.StudyContext ctx) {
        // get the declared variables
       // study(hello = "hello",world = "world")
       // study(hello = "hello",world = "world",name = "name")
        System.out.println("enterStudy");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your grammar:

```
@members {
    public final java.util.List<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> parameters = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
}
```

Modify your assign rule:

```
assign: name=ID '=' value=(INT  | DATA ) {
    parameters.add(new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry($name.text, $value.text));
};
```

Now you can use `StudyParser.parameters` field to access required information:

```
StudyParser parser = ...;
parser.study();
System.out.println(parser.parameters);
```

Also please note that your grammar probably is slightly wrong, because it allows the following input: `study(x=1y=2)`.

Comment: thank you very much, yes i spend a lot of time thinking about how i can solve this but without result, do you have any idea how i can solve it?

Comment: Try `study: 'study' '(' (| ( assign (',' assign)*) ) ')' NEWLINE;` from my quick testing it seems to work.

Comment: Hi, now when I do "prog: study + EOF;"
to have several studies, the parser give me all the parameters together.